# Start Application with flags

Tags: java, android

I have an application:

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void attachBaseContext(Context context){
        if (SomeGlobalState.doStuff) {
            doStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to do some set up of this application in the `attachBaseContext` that can change dependent on a flag I can pass that isn't always passed, so I don't want to add it to the metadata of the manifest.

Is there something in the Android framework that I don't know about where I can pass "Intent-like" extras to an Application or am I going to have to do something hackish to let it know that I want its state to change?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html

Comment: Hmm. Where does the flag originate from, i.e. who sets the flag dependent on what condition? I think that's where my confusion comes from.

Comment: I got it, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this without a file, you can use `adb shell setprop <propname> <value>` and then in your attachBaseContext you can do something like this

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/getprop", MY_PROPERTY});
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
String propertyValue = reader.readLine();
```

Then you can verify that `propertyValue` is equal to whatever you were expecting. Great for testing.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something in the Android framework that I don't know about where I can pass "Intent-like" extras to an Application

No, but you don't need it.

> or am I going to have to do something hackish to let it know that I want its state to change?

If the state is persistent -- and your question suggests that it is -- just use a `SharedPreferences` for that state. The `Application` can retrieve those and use them. And, if the `Application` needs to proactively take steps on a state change, the `Application` can register a listener for `SharedPreferences` changes.

If the state is not persistent -- meaning that the app always starts in state A and may switch to states B-Z based on runtime work -- just call a method on the `Application` at the point of the state change. The `Application` can hold onto the state in a data member.

Comment: I was hoping for something other than a file :-\

Comment: @Kairos: Then I have no idea what you are looking for.

Comment: that's the answer I'm looking for...that something other than a file does or doesn't exist for this purpose.